# Navigation Duplicated in Nuxt.js

Tags: nuxt.js

In my project I have set up a simple nuxt2 with routing but when page refresh it show the error.

`NavigationDuplicated: Avoided redundant navigation to current location: "/haendler-details/1404-distilled-gin"`

Answer (score 0):

This error basically occurs because the you navigate the same route.
So avoid this error you can used exact keyword on nuxt-link

```js
<nuxt-link to="/here-the-path" exact>Go to Distilled Gin</nuxt-link>
```

Comment: is this some kinda hidden feature? because i certainly dont see it  in the documentation https://v2.nuxt.com/docs/features/nuxt-components#the-nuxtlink-component

Comment: you can check this link https://nuxt.com/docs/api/components/nuxt-link